# Import of Recommendation letter from a previously submitted graduate application

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I got accepted to some graduate program in USA as an international student. For some reason I can not start my program this Fall semester. So I have two options now : defer my admission or submit new application. Now if I want to submit a new application, can I import the previous LORs submitted my referees ?

Comment: That's likely going to depend very much on which system the university in question uses. You'll have to talk to the graduate coordinator in that department.

Comment: Is there a challenge deferring?